# .NET MVC Core SendGrid Email Verification not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sendgrid

Following the Microsoft tutorial, as provided below, however still unable to send the email.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

I have spent some time debugging and found out the issue is due to the following code below getting back null values for the SendGridUser and SendGridKey. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thank you!

```
Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
```

Secrets.json

```
{
  "SendGridUser": "apiKeyName",
  "SendGridKey": "<ApiKey>"
}
```

[image]

EmailSender.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjectName.Areas.Identity.Services;

namespace ProjectName.Services
{
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Joe Smith"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

AuthMessageSenderOption.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProjectName.Areas.Identity.Services
{
    public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
    {
        public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
        public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IdentityHostingStartup.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ProjectName.Data;

[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(ProjectName.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace ProjectName.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
                {
                    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration from Startup.cs
Commented out services.AddIdentity as it was causing conflict with the IdentityHostingStartup

```
//services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
//    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
//    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();        

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.AllowAreas = true;
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        });

        // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
        //services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        // requires
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

Comment: in  the tutorial they tell you to put them in user secrets using the command line, did you do that? It is also possible to put them in appsettings.json but in general you want to avoid any sensitive credentials going into source control and you want them to be protected.

Comment: Yep already added the keys via command line

Comment: did you look in the secrets file and you can see the credentials there?

Comment: Yes. Which is kind of weird

Comment: you have registered the settings like this? services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

Comment: Yes. Let me update my EmailSender, AuthMessageSender and IdentityHostingStartup.cs

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: Can you show the call to `services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);` and where `Configuration` itself comes from?

Comment: The configuration should be from the Startup? I'm quite new to this so still learning

Comment: Yeah, if that `Configuration` instance is taken from a parameter that's passed in to your `Startup` constructor, it should be ok. Going right back to the top then - Are you using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` in `Program.cs`?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Everything seems to be in order then. If you want to upload the project to e.g. GitHub, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a mistake on my part. Everything is correct.

The following code below was commented out and replaced to read environment variables from somewhere else and hence the reason the values were null. Thank you very much!

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }
```